# What are the cases when trimToSize() method does not affect the value returned by capacity() method of StringBuffer class in Java?

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder, stringbuffer, capacity

In the specification of trimToSize() method it has been written that :

```
Calling this method may, but is not required to, 
affect the value returned by a subsequent call to the {@link #capacity()} method.
```

What are the conditions when trimToSize() method does not affect the value returned by capacity() method of StringBuffer class in Java ?

Comment: This is probably implementation dependent. Why is this important?

Comment: Just going through the source codes of Java APIs. And got confused at this point.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the start of the `trimToSize` Javadoc says

> **Attempts** to reduce storage used for the character sequence. If the buffer is larger than necessary to hold its current sequence of characters, then it **may be resized** to become more space efficient

It doesn't require the storage to be reduced, and it may not be possible to reduce the storage (and even if it is possible to reduce the storage, the implementation is allowed to decide that it would be more beneficial not to reduce the storage). If the storage is reduced, the result returned by a subsequent call to `capacity()` will change.

That said, the implementation I see in `AbstractStringBuilder` always reduces the storage when possible (i.e. when not all the characters of the backing array are occupied):

```
public void trimToSize() {
    if (count < value.length) {
        value = Arrays.copyOf(value, count);
    }
}
```

Comment: FWIW, the current implementation in OpenJDK does copy everything over to a minimally-sized array when `trimToSize` is called. But this might change between versions.

Comment: @Thilo yep, I just added that when you wrote the comment. Thanks

Comment: The Java11 source is interesting: https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/AbstractStringBuilder.java#L238  It seems they now support Latin-1 in addition to UTF-16 for the internal representation. One byte per character instead of two. (`trimToSize` behaviour is the same though).